# How to downgrade Magento Enterprise 2.x to Community edition

Tags: magento-2.1.8, magento-ce, magento-ee

My site uses **Magento EE 2.1.8**, I want to downgrade to **Magento CE 2.1.8** , I havn't found steps to do that. I just found lot of articles for **Magento 1**.
I see that there are two methods for downgrading,

1. Either deleting some enterprise files and db tables from the enterprise setup, or
2. Install a fresh CE setup and migrate extensions and data.

Any help please?

Comment: Are you using any EE features? e.g. customer credit, gift cards etc.

Comment: No. Im not using any EE feature, thats why I want to downgrade to CE

Comment: Hello @MoeHammadi have you changed anything or created any attributes specific enterprise ?

Comment: Hello @Aditya Shah, What are Enterprise specific attributes? I have created products attributes only.

Comment: Wait let me post an answer it will help you but first take backup of database and code

Comment: Sure I am working on test Environment. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

I have Magento EE 2.2.4 as well Community edition 2.2.4

I have did some r&d for this and I have not found any Magento DevDocs Information regarding this, But I have some idea because I am working in EE and below information might be helpful for you.

I have summon information from multiple source as well with my inputs and my local database for cross check.

**THERE ARE TWO VALUABLE APPROACHES YOU CAN FOLLOW I.E.**

- Removing Unwanted Magento EE files
- Migrating the most usable code from EE version to CE version

> First approach, guides you to downgrade your installation of Magento
>   EE by;

**Removing all enterprise related files**

```
rm -rf app/etc/enterprise 
rm -rf LICENSE_EE.txt 
rm -rf LICENSE_EE.html
```

**Remove enterprise attributes**

Log in into the back-end and check the whole working as expected. Now, click around to create a new product. While creating a new product, it should fail, as your database still carries enterprise attributes that automatically loaded by Magento and the according source files aren’t present there anymore. It can also be fixed easily by removing the unwanted attributes:

```
DELETE FROM eav_attribute WHERE source_model LIKE 'enterprise_%'; DELETE FROM eav_attribute WHERE backend_model LIKE 'enterprise_%'; 

DELETE FROM eav_attribute WHERE attribute_code IN ('gift_wrapping_available', 'gift_wrapping_price');
```

[image]

> Important: Before doing this, always make sure, you don’t require any
>   related data.

**URL Index Fixing**

Clear the rewrite table, to use the URL keys from the enterprise setup and retrieve required IDs and copy the URL keys

```
SELECT @entity_type_id:=entity_type_id FROM eav_entity_type WHERE entity_type_code = 'catalog_product'; 
SELECT @attribute_id:=attribute_id FROM eav_attribute WHERE attribute_code = 'url_key' AND entity_type_id = @entity_type_id; 
UPDATE catalog_product_entity_varchar new INNER JOIN catalog_product_entity_url_key old ON (new.attribute_id = @attribute_id AND new.entity_type_id = @entity_type_id AND old.entity_id = new.entity_id) SET new.value = old.value;
```

Important: Afterward, ensure to re-index everything in Magento’s back-end.

[image]

References

1. https://www.brihaspatitech.com/blog/migrating-from-magento-enterprise-to-magento-community-version-successfully/
2. https://www.transpacific-software.com/blog/migrating-from-magento-enterprise-edition-ee-to-magento-community-version-ce
3. https://www.interactone.com/downgrading-from-magento-enterprise-edition/

> This are OLD references But it helps, Above screens shots of from DB
>   is my local EE 2.2.4 ; I compared CE and EE 2.2.4 and found above
>   changes.

Comment: I am working on it. I will apply the steps , removing unwanted magento EE files. I will get back to you when I finish.

Comment: Yes sure, and keep me updated, First run the SELECT Query than Delete :)

Comment: Hello @MoeHammadi Have you checked it ?

Comment: Hello @Aditya Shah , I am facing some issues in creating a test version of my website because of its size. When I finish setting up the test environment , I will apply the steps above immediately. Thank you

Comment: Hello @Aditya Shah, the query : UPDATE catalog_product_entity_varchar new INNER JOIN catalog_product_entity_url_key old ON (new.attribute_id = attribute_id AND new.entity_type_id = entity_type_id AND old.entity_id = new.entity_id) SET new.value = old.value; 

Table 'catalog_product_entity_url_key' doesn't exist.

Comment: It means Attributes isn't created, In mine I have created for EE

Comment: Then I should skip this step?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88450/discussion-between-aditya-shah-and-moe-hammadi).

Comment: Solution Does not work