# Migrate Magento EE 2.1.8 to Magento CE 2.1.8

Tags: magento-2.1.8

How to migrate Magento Enterprise Version 2.1.8 to Magento Community Version 2.1.8?

I have installed a fresh copy of Magento CE with new database then Transfered the theme and the extensions.

Everything works fine.

Then I changed the database connection to the EE database. When I view a product and go to checkout/Cart, I got the below error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Magento\GiftCard\Model\Attribute\Backend\Giftcard\Amount' not found in /home/user/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php on line 93
```

Knowing that I have disabled all the GiftCard Extensions on the EE version before migration.

Comment: Do you have a "Stack trace" ? Something is trying to load `Magento\GiftCard\Model\Attribute\Backend\Giftcard\Amount` model with ObjectManager. Maybe the stack trace can give us more informations.

Comment: This might be helpful - https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/257419/how-to-downgrade-magento-enterprise-2-x-to-community-edition/258126#258126

Answer (score 0):

I would suggesting NOT copying the Database, because EE have more features/modules installed. This also affects database entires.

I recommend exporting all the data from EE and import it to CE.

Comment: Can I export sales orders?

Comment: not with core functionality https://www.mageplaza.com/review/order-export/

Comment: Is there an article for exporting all data and importing them again. The problem is that there are two systems integrated with magento. So the IDs of products,categories,product_attributes and sales orders should be the same.