# How to downgrade Magento Enterprise 2.3.1 to Community edition

Tags: magento2.3.1, magento2.3.2, magento-ce, magento-ee

My website use Magento EE 2.3.1, I want to downgrade to Magento CE 2.3.2. How can I do it?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think this is up-gradate not downgrade ??

Comment: Yes, But it want down from EE to CE

Comment: I don't know if it is possible, but you can try this: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/258126/31910

Comment: You can also contact with you enterprise support and tell them then you don't want to continue enterprise and you need to switch back to community, they will help you on this